# Internal server error 500, JSON.parse unexpected at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: angular, rest, http, glassfish

I want to send data to my REST server running on glassfish. I get the internal server error 500 all the time and I dont know what is wrong. I searched online but that didn't really help me. My frontend is made with angular and the backend is running on glassfish. I spend hours trying to debug this error but nothing seems to work. I hope someone knows what is wrong here?

Frontend:

```
  public codeValue: string;

  codeList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mcdonalds' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Kentucky Fried Chicken' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Burger King' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Domino`s pizza' },
    { id: 5, name: 'New York Pizza' }
  ];


  @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
  restaurant = {
    id: null,
    name: ''
  };
   httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public saveCode(e): void {
    let name = e.target.value;
    let list = this.codeList.filter(x => x.name === name)[0];



    this.restaurant.id =  list.id;
    this.restaurant.name = list.name;

console.log(list.id);
console.log(list.name);



    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };

    const data = {
      id: list.id,
      name: list.name
    };


    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant',
      (data), httpOptions)


      .subscribe( // subscribe to observable http.post
        res => {
          console.log("response" + " " + res); // log results otherwise log error
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        }
      );
  }
```

Backend code:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response all(){
    List<Restaurant> all = repositoryService.getAllRestaurants();
    return Response
            .status(200)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .entity(all)
            .build();
}



    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response save(Restaurant restaurant){
        repositoryService.save(restaurant);
        return Response
                .status(201)
                .build();
```

Comment: Some photos with the error and what I am trying to send (imgur.com/rIxHWAp) (imgur.com/7lESxmv) (imgur.com/lWR5VRK)

Comment: try to `console.log(res)` to see if there any data

Comment: It sees the data and prints it in json format

Answer (score 1):

Depending what that character is:

> `

you may need to escape it in the JSON you're sending to the backend:

```
{ id: 4, name: 'Domino`s pizza' }
```

To see if that is the problem, remove the character, send the data and if that works, decide whether you really want it and escape it if you do

Comment: I removed, but I have that error with every option i choose